# storing a file name and want to connect bitween the filename and the files folder before sending to client - node

Tags: node.js, angular, express

So I am storing a filenames in the DB, and the files in a folder.
I would like to connect the filename to the file and send the file to the client.
I am not sure how can I do that. would love to get an explanation

here is the images folder -

[image]

here is the response, how can i send the file from there -

```
type IgetProductsResponse = express.Response<
    IServerResponse & {
        data?: {
            id: string;
            category: { value: ProductCategory, label: string };
            gender: { value: ProductGender, label: string };
            title: string;
            description: string;
            price: number;
            imageFileName: string;
        }[];
    }
>;
```

the controller response -

```
try {
    const products = await ProductDB.find({
      category: +req.query.category!,
      gender: +req.query.gender!,
    });

    ServerGlobal.getInstance().logger.info(
      `<getProducts>: Successfully got the products filtered by \
category ${req.query.category} and gender ${req.query.gender}`
    );

    res.status(200).send({
      success: true,
      message: "Successfully retrieved products",
      data: products.map((product) => ({
        id: product.id as string,
        category: {
          value: product.category,
          label: ServerGlobal.getInstance().getCategoryLabel(product.category)!,
        },
        gender: {
          value: product.gender,
          label: ServerGlobal.getInstance().getGenderLabel(product.gender)!,
        },
        title: product.title,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price,
        imageFileName: product.imageFileName,
      })),
    });
    return;
```

front end - angular -

http-service -

```
  public getProducts(
    gender?: ProductGender,
    category?: ProductCategory
  ): Observable<IGetProductsResponse> {
    const baseUrl = ENDPOINT;

    return this.http.get<IGetProductsResponse>(
    `${baseUrl + 'list?gender=' + gender}&category=${category}`
    );  
  }
```

service-

```
 public getProducts(
    gender?: ProductGender,
    category?: ProductCategory
  ): Observable<IProductInterface[]> {
    return this.httpProductService.getProducts(gender, category).pipe(
      catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMessage: string;

        switch (errorResponse.status) {
          case 400:
            errorMessage = 'Getting products failed';
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = 'An error occurred';
        }

        return throwError(errorMessage);
      }),
      map((response: IGetProductsResponse) => response.data!)
    );
  }
```

resolver -

```
class ProductsResolver implements Resolve<IProductInterface[]> {

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProductInterface[]> {
    return this.productService.getProducts(
      +route.queryParamMap.get('gender')! as ProductGender,
      +route.queryParamMap.get('category')! as ProductCategory,
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to respond to an HTTP request with a file whose path you know, [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) will help you.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen added some code, i am not sure how can i compre the filename from DB to the file from the folder

Comment: Your code produces JSON responses, but your question sounds as if you want to respond with a .jpeg or .png file. Do you want to combine both into _one_ response? That would not be convenient to consume.

Comment: i want to compare what i get from the DB to the files folder and send the File to the client side

Comment: But you have a **list** of products and you can send only the file for _one_ product. How do you choose which?

Comment: the response is an array which based on querys that get products by gender and category. so if it will get 5 products, i need to compare 5 filenames to files @HeikoTheißen

Comment: The answer to your question will depend on the way you consume the response on the client. You should include details about the client-side framework that you use.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen added. if you need more tell me